# How to build task 'android:config'

Tags: android, ruby, rubygems, rubymotion

I'm trying to work with motion-game gem, I followed all the steps to setup rubymotion and motion-game, but some of the main features of motion-game gem aren't working.

I ran:

```
motion create --template=motion-game HelloGame
cd HelloGame
rake android:config
```

then this happens

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'android:config'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motion-game gem needs Rails 4.0 to work. 
I installed and it worked fine.